# AngularJS Exception Handler: Using service with unknown provider injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I'm using AngularJS and I've created a custom exception handler.

```
angular.module('moduleName')
    .factory('$exceptionHandler, () => {

        return (exception, cause) => {

            try {
                var someService = $injector.get('serviceName');
                someService.alert(exception);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                window.alert(ex);
            }
        };
    })
```

I caught up a situation when i forgot to run a script (in the html page) of one of the injections services that the service (named 'serviceName') are using. This has caused an exception when there is a use of the 'alert' function of the service.

I added the try/catch code in order to use regular 'alert' function whenever the service is malfunction (wrong injection or couldn't initialized) so the flow of the application won't hurt and in case of an exception handler exception catch, the code will run with or without the service.

However, even with the try zone, when there is use of the alert function of the service (when the service is malfunction), the $exceptionHandler function is invoked again instead of reaching to the catch zone...

Is there a way to get to the catch zone instead of invoking again the $exceptionHandler function? or is there a different way i could use in order to see if the service is good to use and all of his injections were loaded correctly?

Thanks in advanced